# People picker values are blank in email sent from sharepoint infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, people-picker

I have an infopath 2010 browser enabled form deployed to a sharepoint 2010  site. Upon submit i have configured it to send the **active view** of the form to myself as an email. When i look into the email that i have got the active view has all the data that i filled  in **except for the data that i filled in the **people picker**** control is blank! When i test this form in infopath filler the email has the valued keyed in people picker control.

Any help in this regards is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How exactly did you do "Ran into this same problem myself. What I did was add a text field and populate that field (on submit) with the name that was selected from the people picker. Then I setup a rule to hide this field so it does not show on the original form.'

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this same problem myself. What I did was add a text field and populate that field (on submit) with the name that was selected from the people picker. Then I setup a rule to hide this field so it does not show on the original form.

Then I tested it by having it submit the active view of the form using email (not as an attachment) and it was populated.

It has something to do with the people picker being only a secondary data source and not technically stored in the form.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the similar problem. What I did was to have two different forms(New Form and display form).

The display form which is configured when New form is submitted.

In display form, just drag and drop the "display name"[Repeating section] from people picker field (to select this --> Advanced view (field))

Lets say people picker name is

```
"Feedback Raiser Name" 
pc:person 
**DisplayName**
AccountId 
AccountType
```

This should populate the value from people picker in email form.